# runZonedGuarded not catching Dio exceptions on route

Tags: flutter, dio

I have setup with Dio exceptions thrown depending on status code that I want to handle with runZonedGuarded onError, the problem is that the exceptions are not caught by it, though they are being thrown by Dio. runZonedGuarded wont handle unless I am routing to another page with an API call that throws an exception but never on the same route.

My Dio code:

```
  Future<Response<dynamic>> request(RequestType requestType, String url, {dynamic data, String? token}) async {
    Options? extraOptions = token != null ? _authBuildOptions(token) : null;
    try {
      if (requestType == RequestType.GET) {
        return await _client.get(url, queryParameters: data, options: extraOptions);
      } else if (requestType == RequestType.POST) {
        return await _client.post(url, data: data, options: extraOptions);
      } else if (requestType == RequestType.PUT) {
        return await _client.put(url, data: data, options: extraOptions);
      } else if (requestType == RequestType.DELETE) {
        return await _client.delete(url, queryParameters: data, options: extraOptions);
      } else {
        throw Exception('"_request" has an Undefined request type');
      }
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      if (e.response == null) throw NetworkException();

      switch (e.response?.statusCode) {
        case 400:
          throw ValidationException(data: e.response?.data);
        case 401:
          throw UnauthenticatedException();
        case 403:
          throw ForbiddenException();
        case 426:
          throw UpgradeException(data: e.response?.data);
        case 429:
          throw TooManyRequestsException();
        default:
          throw APIException();
      }
    }
  }
```

My main code:

```
void asyncErrorHandler(error, stackTrace) {
  errorHandler(error);
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('ERROR: $error, STACKTRACE: $stackTrace');
  }
}

errorHandler(error) {
  if (error is UnauthenticatedException || error is ForbiddenException) {
    final authController = Get.find<AuthController>();
    authController.unAuthenticate();
    Get.offAllNamed(routes.login);
  } else if (error is NetworkException) {
    Get.offAllNamed(routes.noInternet);
  } else if (error is APIException) {
    Get.defaultDialog(
      textConfirm: 'back'.tr,
      title: 'errorTitle'.tr,
      onConfirm: () => Get.offAllNamed(routes.home),
      middleText: 'errorInServer'.tr,
    );
  } else if (error is UpgradeException) {
    Get.offNamedUntil(routes.update, (_) => false, arguments: {
      'version': error.appVersion.version,
      'version_number': error.appVersion.versionNumber,
      'download_link': error.appVersion.downloadLink,
      'force_update': error.appVersion.forceUpdate,
      'comments': error.appVersion.comments
    });
  }
}

void mainDelegate() => main();

Future<void> main() async {
  runZonedGuarded<Future<void>>(() async {
    await dotenv.load(fileName: ".env");
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    initServices();
    runApp(App());
  }, asyncErrorHandler);
}
```

I have tried solutions from the flutter github, but the solutions didn't fix the issues I am facing. I am thinking it's something to do with runZonedGuarded, but I can't figure out why, I have debugged Dio code to see if the exceptions are being thrown and they are.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the options

```
options: Options(
  followRedirects: false,
  validateStatus: (status) {
    return status! < 500;
  },
),
```

Comment: This caused it to not get handled at all